# In an IP filter, where does the IP I'm trying to block goes: source or destination?

Tags: networking, router, ip, web-filtering

I'm  trying to block a certain site/ip-address (`http://122.160.230.125:8080/vta/redirectedPage.do`) from opening.

I figure (?) that if I could put `122.160.230.125` in my router IP Filter settings I could block that site but I'm not sure which field to put it in, source or destination?

Comment: Image is low, you can block pc from your lan to internet or vice versa by IP and filter by port too.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it (both combinations) and perform a ping to that address to test.  If this filter behaves like you expect and from what I see, it should be blocking ALL traffic (ICMP included) to that IP address.